# EAR - referring to class in another project results in NoClassDef

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am using WebLogic Server v10.3

In my WebLogic Workshop I created a Portal EAR project, as well as two other projects:

A Portal Web Project
Web Services Project

Now the portal web project references a class in the web services project.  Everything builds and publishes fine, but when I try running the web project, I get a NoClassDefFound for the class that I am refererring to in Web Services Project.  I checked the Java EE Module Dependencies in the EAR project, both web project and web services project are there.  What else am I missing?

Comment: are those being deployed? are you seeing any entries in server log with deployment details?

Comment: yes deploys fine, there are no errors in the logs